# How to close react native app and keep on native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am doing a component on React Native and it will be called inside the native app of each platform, Android and iOS.

This component has a back button to go back to the native app.

Is it possible to acomplish?

Already tried with:

```
navigation.getBack();
```

and

```
BackHandler.exitApp();
```

but as understood, it only goes back in the screens that exist and the other closes the app.

Thanks to any information possible.

Comment: On Android is this a separate Activity?  Fragment?  Something else?  In the first two cases you'll likely need to call the native navigation function (finish() for an Activity or pop the fragment stack for a fragment) when the back stack is empty.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes, it is a separate activity, I am going to try something around your answer, thanks